# Classe privada ou protegida no PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, private, protected

É possível criar uma classe privada ou protegida no PHP de forma a permitir acesso aos suas variáveis e funções apenas a outras classes específicas?

**Aplicação:** tenho uma classe em que crio uma conexão com o banco de dados e queria permitir o acesso a essa classe apenas a outras classes que realizam CRUD no banco de dados

#### conexao.php

```
<?php
class Conexao extends Mysqli {
    private static $conexao = null;

    function Conexao($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco) {
        parent::__construct($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        self::$conexao->close();
    }

    public static function getConexao() {
        if(!isset(self::$conexao)){
            self::$conexao = new Conexao("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "nome_banco");

            if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            if (false === self::$conexao->set_charset('utf8')) {
                die("Error ao usar utf8");
            }
        }
        return self::$conexao;
    }
}
```

#### usuario.php

```
<?php
require_once "conexao.php";

class DAO_usuario {
    private $conexao = null;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conexao = Conexao::getConexao();
    }

    public function cadastrar_usuario($nome, $usuario, $senha, ...) {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

**Observação:** não uso nem vou usar *frameworks*, apenas PHP puro

O foco da pergunta é OOP, mas seria interessante comentar sobre o equivalente no estilo procedural

Comment: você pode usar o  extends do  php  dessa forma  a  classe vai  passar a fazer  parte da outra e qualquer classe que tente fazer o  include  ou  usar o  name space não poderá   o codigo fica mais ou  menos assim
classBanco extends outraclass >> http://php.net/manual/en/reflection.extending.php

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons no caso então eu faria `class DAO_usuario extends Conexao`, `class DAO_produto extends Conexao`, ...?

Comment: Os membros declarados como protegidos só podem ser acessados na classe declarante e suas classes herdeiras, os declarados como privados só podem ser acessados na classe que define o membro privado.

Comment: @FabianoMonteiro pode exemplificar isso numa resposta?

Comment: Então, meu comentário é baseado no php.net. Uma explicação completa vc encontrará aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.visibility.php
Aguém pode resumir como uma resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP não suporta classes privadas, e pelo que entendi nem é o que você quer.

Mesmo em outras linguagens dizer quem pode chamar uma classe não costuma ser possível, a não ser colocando a visibilidade dela no mesmo pacote, então não diz quem pode acessar, mas diz onde pode ser acessada.

PHP não tem nada parecido, afinal É uma linguagem de *script*. E em *scripts* é fácil administrar o uso de classes (ainda que acho estranho *scripts* terem classes). Se for algo complexo que precisa mesmo deste controle, não são *scripts*, e aí PHP parece não ser a linguagem adequada.

Em nenhuma linguagem existe classe protegida.

Não tem como proteger uma classe, então não tem como dizer como fazer isto, só dá para dizer que não é possível. Portanto a recompensa foi colocada sem necessidade, a não ser que nem a pergunta, nem a recompensa não estejam claros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ok, eu não posso declarar a classe privada mas posso declarar seus métodos e variáveis, no caso tem como permitir o acesso a um método, apenas por algumas classes?

Comment: Não, se nem a classe é possível, métodos menos ainda. Claro, pode impedir o acesso à qualquer classe, ou apenas às classes que herdam dela, mas se fizer uma herança só por causa disto está fazendo algo muito errado. Eu já questiono (mas não afirmo) se Conexao deveria herdar de MySQL.

Comment: Obrigado, e como eu poderia _"impedir o acesso à qualquer classe"_?

Comment: Quando você diz que _"PHP não suporta classes privadas"_, isso significa que também não suporta classes protegidas (`protected`) certo?

Comment: Sobre _"mas se fizer uma herança só por causa disto está fazendo algo muito errado."_, poderia explicar um pouco mais?

Comment: Você pode fazer uma imensa gambiarra com validaçoes no `__construct`, de forma a retornar a instancia apenas se passar na validação. Mas é apenas uma hipótese e totalmente gambiarrosa, não recomenda. O que o @Maniero diz faz muito sentido, se isso é crucial para seu projeto, procure implementar uma linguagem que atenda os requisitos naturalmente.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam a herança deve ser feita quando precisa estender uma classe, não para proteger algo. Precisa ter uma relação direta, a derivada precisa ser a mesma coisa que a base, com algo a mais. A questão toda é muito simples: não dá para proteger como quer, não faz sentido querer isto, não tem utilidade, não é conceitualmente correto, especialmente em PHP que é uma linguagem de *script*. Em algumas linguagens que permitem produzir soluções complexas é possível permitir proteger para um grupo específico, mas não individualmente, a não ser com ferramentas externas criadas por você.

Comment: @Maniero conhece alguma forma de impedir (ou pelo menos dificultar) que uma classe ou uma função seja instanciada em qualquer arquivo?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam funções não são instanciadas. Classes podem ser impedidas de serem instanciadas, mas não é o que pede na pergunta. Veja [classes abstratas](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

Comment: Ok, mas é possível que alguém consiga criar conexões onde não deveria e acessar meu banco de dados já que minha classe que cria essa conexão é pública? Apenas para teste, a partir dos links e da resposta do @TomMelo criei uma classe de conexão abstrata e a estendi em uma classe com o DAO acredito que a diferença de segurança seja insignificativa (isso se existir). A ideéia era só tentar proteger mais a minha conexão com o banco não é algo essencial para a aplicação

Comment: Não, isto não é possível, você está preocupado com as coisas erradas, segurança é outra coisa, nada isso vai dar segurança. Novamente o que deseja não é possível eme nenhuma linguagem, menos ainda em PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**ATENÇÃO AQUI**

---

Do ponto de vista OOP o que você quer fazer não tem muito sentido e a resposta do @Maniero está correta. Realmente considere repensar o que você está tentando fazer.

**NÃO MUITA ATENÇÃO AQUI**

---

Agora, já que o PHP nos possibilita muitas "soluções alternativas" :trollface:, vou deixar aqui uma "alternativa"(que não deveria ser usada) que talvez te de alguma outra ideia.

Lembrando que essa "alternativa" não garante absolutamente nada do que você está tentando fazer e ainda pode colocar **problemas** dentro da sua aplicação.

Arquivos no diretório:

```
dao.php
abstract-dao.php
user-dao.php
invalid-dao.php
test.php
```

Essa "alternativa" consiste em forçar a implementação de uma **interface** para a utilização de uma classe que contém a conexão com o banco de dados.

DAO interface:

```
<?php

    interface DAO
    {
        public function insert($entity);
        public function update($entity);
        public function delete($entity);
    }

?>
```

AbstractDAO class:

```
<?php    

    abstract class AbstractDAO
    {
        private $conn;
        private const SHOULD_IMPLEMENT = "DAO";

        public function __construct()
        {
            $called_class = get_called_class();
            $implements_array = class_implements($called_class);

            if (!in_array(self::SHOULD_IMPLEMENT, $implements_array))
            {
                throw new Exception("DAO interface must be implemented");
            }

            // inicializa a conexão...
            $this->conn = "Conexão Válida\n";
        }

        protected function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->conn;
        }
    }

?>
```

UserDAO class(Classe válida para utilizar a conexão com a base):

```
<?php

    require_once "abstract-dao.php";
    require_once "dao.php";

    class UserDAO extends AbstractDAO implements DAO
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function insert($entity)
        {
            echo parent::getConnection();
        }

        public function update($entity)
        {
            echo parent::getConnection();
        }

        public function delete($entity)
        {
            echo parent::getConnection();
        }
    }

?>
```

InvalidDAO class(Classe que não deve usar a conexão):

```
<?php

    require_once "abstract-dao.php";
    require_once "dao.php";

    // classe não implementa a interface DAO

    class InvalidDAO extends AbstractDAO
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function try_get_connection()
        {
            echo parent::getConnection();
        }
    }

?>
```

Testando:

```
<?php

    require_once "user-dao.php";
    require_once "invalid-dao.php";

    $userDAO = new UserDAO();
    $userDAO->insert("qualquer coisa");

    // exception
    $invalidDAO = new InvalidDAO();
    $invalidDAO->try_get_connection();

?>
```

Para mais informações sobre as funções utilizadas para a validação:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-called-class.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.class-implements.php

Answer (score 0):

Não é possivel declarar uma classe privada. Porem você pode declarar um metodo como privado, so será possivel acessa-lo instanciando a classe do metodo. Poderia ser feito até pelo construtor usando metodo privado ou dependendo da necessidade protected.

```
private function conexao($user,$pass,$url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade é utilizar [anonymous classes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.anonymous.php):

```
<?php

class DAO_usuario {
    static protected $conexao = null;

    public function __construct() {
        if (self::$conexao) {
            return;
        }

        self::$conexao = (new class($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco) extends Mysqli {
            public function __construct($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco) {
                parent::__construct("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "nome_banco");

                if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                    die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
                }

                // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions !
                if (false === $this->set_charset('utf8')) {
                    die("Error ao usar utf8");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        self::$conexao->close();
    }

    public function cadastrar_usuario($nome, $usuario, $senha) {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

Para todos os efeitos você tem aí uma classe privada, ninguém além da classe externa e quem quer que extenda ela vai ter acesso.

Você ainda poderia melhor isso tendo uma classe abstract DAO com esse construtor, sendo que `DAO_usuario` e outros DAOs estenderiam ela e compartilhariam a mesma única conexão/"classe privada".